# Why is my subclass of a UITableViewCell saying that it's a UIView class in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile

I've subclassed the `UITableViewCell` class, one works and the other does not and I don't know why.

This is the function that throws the error:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    NSString *type = [object objectForKey:@"type"];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"quote"]) {

        QuoteCell *cell = (QuoteCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[QuoteCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        }
        cell.contentText.text = [object objectForKey:self.textKey];
        NSDate *date = object.createdAt;
        cell.datetimeLabel.text = [NSDate stringForDisplayFromDate:date];
        return cell;
    }
    else if([type isEqualToString:@"photo"])
    {
        TestCell *cell = (TestCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TestCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        }
        return cell;
    }

    return nil;

}
```

For a reason that I can't figure out, one of the subclasses of the `UITableViewCell`, the `TestCell` class, says that it is a `UIView` instead of a `UITableViewCell`?  I sublcassed the two classes from `UITableViewCell` exactly the same I think but the `QuoteCell` works and says that its a `UITableViewCell` and the `TestCell` doesn't and says that its a `UIView`.

Here is the error -

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x96b7b70'

Any Ideas?

After being stuck on this issue for a couple of hours, I figured it out 10 minutes after I posted.  It had to do with how I was creating the UITableViewCells.  I am creating classes that extend UITableViewCell and in the TestCell.m initWithStyle function I get the nibArray from the MainBundle but because I have a UIImageView in the cell the index of the cell itself actually changes so I had to change the index to find the nib in the array that was the cell itself.  Thanks everyone that responded already.

Comment: Go ahead and set a breakpoint for all exceptions. In the moment when the execption is thrown then you see the same error message plus the line of code where it is thrown. You may have to press continue 2 or 3 times before you see all the information. Then get back to us with this line of code and we try to figure out why there is (most probably) an UIView accessed when an UITableViewCell is expected.

Comment: test cell is a subclass of UIVIew. So for Uiview you can't set tableviewstyle

Comment: After being stuck on this issue for a couple of hours, I figured it out 10 minutes after I posted.  It had to do with how I was creating the UITableViewCells.  I am creating classes that extend UITableViewCell and in the TestCell.m initWithStyle function I get the nibArray from the MainBundle but because I have a UIImageView in the cell the index of the cell itself actually changes so I had to change the index to find the nib in the array that was the cell itself.  Thanks Hermann and Uma.

Answer (score 0):

The exception `-[UIView setTableViewStyle:]` is not on a `UITableViewCell` since `setTableViewStyle:` is a `UITableView` method. So you might want to look on how you are creating the tableView.